Is makeinfo available for Sequoia 15.01?
I am trying to install a toolchain for an M2 Mac and get the error:
'makeinfo' is missing on your system.
     You should only need it if you modified a '.texi' file, or
     any other file indirectly affecting the aspect of the manual.
     You might want to install the Texinfo package:
     <http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/>
     The spurious makeinfo call might also be the consequence of
     using a buggy 'make' (AIX, DU, IRIX), in which case you might
     want to install GNU make:
     <http://www.gnu.org/software/make/>

So, I tried to solve it by downloading the latest make version. However, it seems like it was not written for macOS. Can someone tell me how to fix the error or if makeinfo is available for Sequoia 15.01?

GNU software often has very long, complicated chains of dependencies. Practically speaking, you need a third-party package manager such as MacPorts or Homebrew to install it. Either that, or use Docker to run it in a container, or else install Linux in a virtual machine. The latter may not work if you’re trying to build something to run directly on the host machine.

makeinfo is not part of make.  @LincDavis mentions MacPorts, makeinfo is contained as part of the texinfo package.
